# Jenkins Pipeline file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am in the process of writing a declarative jenkinsfile to build a pipeline project.  Some of the steps within a few of the stages will require some remote commands to be run.  The remote ssh sites have been configured in the main jenkins configuration.

How can I declare these steps within my jenkinsfile?  I know I can run shell commands locally using sh but it's the remote servers that i need to know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install [ssh-agent](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent) plugin then you will be able to execute remote commands using ssh. Check this for [examples](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/)